# Which limits commute with all colimits in $T(h)$-local spectra?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, chromatic-homotopy

Consider the category $Sp_{T(h)}$ of $T(h)$-local spectra. Let $J, K$ be small $\infty$-categories. Recall that $J$-limits said to *commute* with $K$-colimits in $Sp_{T(h)}$ if, for all functors $F : J \times K \to Sp_{T(h)}$, the canonical map

$$\varinjlim_{k \in K} \varprojlim_{j \in J} F(j,k) \to \varprojlim_{j \in J} \varinjlim_{k \in K} F(j,k)$$

is an equivalence.

**Question:** For which small $\infty$-categories $J$ do $J$-limits commute with $K$-colimits in $Sp_{T(h)}$ for *all* small $\infty$-categories $K$?

There are some noteworthy examples of such $J$. In all cases, the reasoning is "$J$-limits can be re-expressed in terms colimits, which always commute with colimits by the "Fubini rule".  (Indeed, such colimits are [absolute](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/absolute+colimit), and general nonsense entails that when $J$ answers to the Question, there is always an argument of this form).

1. Idempotent splitting is a form of limit which commutes with colimits in $Sp_{T(h)}$ (simply because $Sp_{T(h)}$ is an $\infty$-category).
2. Finite limits commute with colimits in $Sp_{T(h)}$ (because $Sp_{T(h)}$ is [stable](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stable+%28infinity%2C1%29-category)).
3. Limits indexed by [$\pi$-finite spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+type+with+finite+homotopy+groups) commute with colimits in $Sp_{T(h)}$ (because $Sp_{T(h)}$ is $\infty$-[ambidextrous](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Ambidexterity+in+K%28n%29-Local+Stable+Homotopy+Theory)).

There is also some mixing and matching which can occur between the above examples. But what does the general picture look like?

Comment: This seems to be equivalent to J-limits preserving filtered colimits, since the functor of J-limits is exact.